# Getting an exception when performing Condition awaits?

Tags: java, monitors

I am getting an Exception everytime I run the following multithreaded code with Monitors.

http://pastebin.com/jTGR98W9
http://pastebin.com/hKvuDX2d

Everytime I perform a condition signal, I get an exception, which says that it should be exclusive, it is however exclusive, given that it is synchronized. Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us the exact exception you are getting and the code for Monitor? I cannot see where you use the Lock nor synchronized in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the old intrinsic locks and their signaling mechanism (`synchronized`, `wait` and `notify`) with the new `Lock` and `Condition` classes, though they don't have any relationship. This is a source for confusion, so I'd stick to one of them (preferably `Lock` and `Condition`).

Your problem is probably caused by not holding the lock that is associated to the condition when you are calling `signal()`. Surround the methods with calls to `lock()` and `unlock():`

```
public void canEat(String name) {
   lock.lock();
   try {
       eaters.add(name);
       if (eaters.size() > 0) {
          canFeed.signal();
       }
   } finally {
       lock.unlock();
   }
}
```

The same needs to be done for the other `synchronized` methods.